# What can we conclude about $a$ if $a^2=a$ in a monoid or semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I found the following question in a test paper:

> Suppose $G$ is a monoid or a semigroup. $a\in G$ and $a^2=a$. What can we say
>   about $a$?

Monoids are associative and have an identity element. Semigroups are just associative.

I'm not sure what we can say about $a$ in this case other than that $a$ could be other things apart from the identity. Any idea if there's a definitive answer to this question?

Comment: you can conclude that $a^n=a$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Surb For semigroup or monoid? Also, I guess they're asking what we can "conclude about $a$" in the sense that what the restrictions on $a$ are

Comment: Okay that one looks trivial as $a^2=a$. So we can write $a.a^2=a.a=a$ and so on....Probably they're looking for something more specific.

Comment: We can conclude that our monoid is not a free monoid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid

Answer (score 0):

If the test is for an introductory abstract algebra course, I say $a$ is an idempotent element of $G$.

Comment: Well, that is quite obvious (almost by definition). I'm perhaps looking for the restrictions on $a$ if $a$ is idempotent and an element of a semigroup or a monoid

Comment: Can we draw any conclusions from associativity and existence of identity?

Comment: @user48929 I think we may need more contexts to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Several things can be said on $a$:

1. $a$ is idempotent,
2. $a$ is regular,
3. the subsemigroup generated by $a$ is trivial,
4. the [$\mathcal{H}$-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) of $a$ is a group.

Make your choice!

Answer (score 0):

$$\{1,a,a^2,a^3,...\} = \{1,a,a,aa^2,...\} = \{1,a,a,a^2,...\} = \{1,a,a,a,...\} = \{1,a\}$$